# Inserting attributesOfItemAtPath into NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, nsfilemanager

NSDictionary * properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:myString error:nil];

I need this to work with a NSURL instead of myString.

I'm still new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL *myURL; // assume this is filled with a file:// URL
NSDictionary * properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[myURL path] error:nil];

// Alternatively for example Creation Date 
NSDate *creationDate = nil;
BOOL success = [myURL getResourceValue:&creationDate forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:NULL]) {
```